# Get foreground app's View

Tags: android, android-activity, android-view

I know I can get the current foreground app’s name by

```
RunningTaskInfo taskInfo = activityManager.getRunningTasks(1).get(0);
ComponentName compName = taskInfo.topActivity;
```

I am wondering is there a way to get the foreground app’s `View` instance? If there is no such API available, is there any hidden api for this in Android?

**I saw a comment which misunderstand my question, so I'd like to emphasis here:**
I am not asking for a solution to get the recent apps usage list. I am asking about get the foreground app's `View` instance.

Comment: you mean you would like to know what is currently at screen?

Comment: I don't thing it's possible..is that??

Comment: I mean I want to get the View instance of the foreground whatever app. According to my research, there seems no easy way. That's why I am asking here, maybe some hidden api ?

Comment: @maveň, please read my question carefully.

Comment: I'm starting to feel like you're trying to create some very malicious code. Your questions on StackOverflow are how to get other apps click events, how to screen capture other apps, how to get other apps views.

Answer (score 3):

> I am wondering is there a way to get the foreground app’s View instance?

That is not possible. `Views` are Java objects. The `Views` of another app are in that app's heap space in that app's process, not yours.